# Why does Red Phosphorus react so violently with an oxidizer like Potassium Chlorate?

Tags: combustion, explosives, physical-organic-chemistry

In Armstrong's Mixture, mixing those two chemicals results in a friction sensitive explosive which produces a loud bang. According to wikipedia, it is made by adding a strong oxidizer to red phosphorus, but what is the explanation as to why it reacts so strongly? Thank you

Comment: Because Phosporus is very easily oxidised and the reaction releases a lot of energy. P-P bonds are weak (200 Kj/mol) and easily broken to initiate the reaction

Comment: $\ce{P-P}$ bonds are very weak due to high angle strain. This makes phosphorus very reactive. White phosphorus is the most reactive but might not be used because it can release too much energy.